# Getting error in Firebase cloud database while creating database

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

I am creating database as shown in Firebase document. But I am getting error of Arrays. But I am not using any array.

Here is my code:

```
private void addNewContact() {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText())){
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email.getText())) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phone.getText())){

                Map<String, Object> newContact = new HashMap<>();
                newContact.put(NAME_KEY, name.getText());
                newContact.put(EMAIL_KEY, email.getText());
                newContact.put(PHONE_KEY, phone.getText());

                db.collection("PhoneBook").document("Contacts").set(newContact)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(FirebaseCloudActivity.this, "User Registered",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(FirebaseCloudActivity.this, "ERROR" + e.toString(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.d("TAG", e.toString());
                            }
                });

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Getting below error:-

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not serialize object. Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase attempts to serialize getters, and firebase attempting to serialize the result of the `.getText()`.

Please Change your Map to this :

```
Map<String, Object> newContact = new HashMap<>();
newContact.put(NAME_KEY, name.getText().toString());
newContact.put(EMAIL_KEY, email.getText().toString());
newContact.put(PHONE_KEY, phone.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ashish. You have saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
newContact.put(NAME_KEY, name.getText());
```

To:

```
newContact.put(NAME_KEY, name.getText().toString());
```

Firebase attempts to serialize getters, and this was the similar issue here with firebase attempting to serialize the result of the .getText().